# Saving instances of model to ManyToMany field thows AttributeError 'Post' object has no attribute 'save_m2m' but when db is checked, has saved

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

My Django 3.1.7 blog app has a Post model with a tags field, which is a ManyToManyField to the PostTag model. I want my users to be able to select from some popular tags, or add their own in the new_tags field I created in models.py. new_tags does not exist in the Post model.

[image]

My idea was to grab the string of "new" tags, split it at the spaces, then check if the tag already existed - creating it if it does exist. That bit of code is working, as new tags are being added to the database.

My issue comes when I try to attach these new tags to the instance of Post being updated with the form.

I have read loads of SO posts, and have arrived at the view code below. This does save the new tags to the Post instance in the database. However, on submitting the form it still throws an AttributeError: `'Post' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'` However if I remove the `post.save_m2m()` line, the instances are created, but are not attached to my Post instance.

**views.py**

```py
class EditPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    """ Renders view to edit an existing post """
    model = Post
    template_name = 'edit_post.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    form_class = EditPostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        
        post = form.save(commit=False)

        new_tags = self.request.POST.get('new_tags')
        tags_list = new_tags.split()

        for new_tag in tags_list:
            post.tags.add(PostTag.objects.get_or_create(name=new_tag)[0])

        post.save_m2m()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        
        return reverse(
            'post_detail',
            kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk, 'slug': self.object.slug})
```

I am confused as to why the code works, but still throws an error. And what I can do to fix it!
Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong, or where I can go from here, are very much appreciated!!

**forms.py**

```py
class EditPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Create form for edit post pg
    """
    ...
    new_tags = forms.CharField(
        max_length=300, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'pattern': '[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+',
            }
        ))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            ...
            'tags',
            'new_tags'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'tags': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
```

**models.py**

I've removed extra fields from the Post model so as to not complicate the question. You can see the full model [here](https://github.com/AJGreaves/thelibrary/blob/a7910da1e5cf3f68914b3bec2c3f64d7866c5308/posts/models.py) if it is needed

```py
class PostTag(models.Model):
    """
    Create tags for posts.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Post(models.Model):
    """
    Create an instance of Post
    """
    
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=70,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "This post title already exists, please choose another."
        })
    
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        PostTag, related_name='post_tags', blank=True)
    
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.save_m2m(…)` is a method of the `form`, not the `Post` model, you thus should call this with:

```
class EditPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    # …

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        new_tags = self.request.POST.get('new_tags')
        tags_list = new_tags.split()

        for new_tag in tags_list:
            post.tags.add(PostTag.objects.get_or_create(name=new_tag)[0])
        form.save_m2m()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**EDIT**: this will not suffice, since the `form.save_m2m()` will call `.set()` on the many-to-many relation, and thus remove the old items. I would advise to rewrite this to:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class EditPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    # …

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save()  save to the database, including the tags
        new_tags = self.request.POST.get('new_tags')
        tags_list = new_tags.split()
        for new_tag in tags_list new_tags.split():
            post.tags.add(PostTag.objects.get_or_create(name=new_tag)[0])
        
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did try that, and gave it another try now. When I test it, I don't get any errors. It creates the new PostTags. However, it doesn't save them to the Post.

Comment: @AJG: that is likely because the underlying model `save_m2m` will clear the m2m relation and insert only the ones that are added.

Comment: THANK YOU so much! That worked. I really appreciate you taking the time to help with this. I was stuck on it for most of the day.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/):

> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm subclass

Call .save_m2m() on form instead of post.